# If field exists then echo "something" in MySQL and BASH, else insert into table - Output to variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, variables

I'm attempting to write a little BASH script that will check for a number in a MySQL database, and if that number is already in the table to `echo "AHHH THAT'S ALREADY THERE"` and then if it's not in the database already to insert it into it..

```
mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb << EOF
SELECT * FROM mylittletable WHERE thenumber=$THENUMBER ;
EOF

mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb << EOF
INSERT INTO mylittletable VALUES ('$THENUMBER,'$THEDATE');
EOF
```

I guess a starting point would be to put the output of the MySQL query into a variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put results of mysql command line query into bash script variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301780/put-results-of-mysql-command-line-query-into-bash-script-variable)

Comment: That's helpful, but I really need the "if it's already there" bit to work - bit of a noob here..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, forget about testing the query results in Bash. You can do what you want (ie insert the data only when it doesn't exist) with just one SQL query :

```
INSERT INTO mylittletable(thenumber, thedate)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$THENUMBER', '$THEDATE') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mylittletable WHERE thenumber = '$THENUMBER'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Even simpler : if your `thenumber` column is the primary key, or if you put a **UNIQUE** constraint on it, you can just use `INSERT IGNORE` (this will make the query silently fail when you try to insert the same number) :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mylittletable VALUES ('$THENUMBER','$THEDATE');
```

Personally, I would go with that second option. Consider creating a UNIQUE constraint if it makes sense for your data (or make `thenumber` a primary key if your table doesn't already have one) :

```
ALTER TABLE mylittletable ADD UNIQUE(thenumber);
```

**EDIT :**

If you want Bash to output something in case of a problem, just do an `INSERT` (without `IGNORE`) and use the exit status of the mysql client program :

```
echo "INSERT INTO mylittletable VALUES ($THENUMBER,'$THEDATE');" | mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb 2> /dev/null || echo Warning!
```

Or if you don't like long one-liners :

```
mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb 2> /dev/null << EOF
INSERT INTO mylittletable VALUES ($THENUMBER,'$THEDATE');
EOF

if [ $? -neq 0 ]
then
    echo Warning!
fi
```

In case you're not familiar with it, the `||` operator is used like this in Bash :

```
# If command1 fails, run command2
command1 || command2
# Silly example
ls myfile 2> /dev/null || echo "No myfile here!"
```

Notice I also use an error redirection : `2> /dev/null` so that errors are not output to the console.

Comment: Excellent! How would I then get Bash to echo a warning if the number did already exist (the number in question is the primary key too by the way)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one too.

```
#!/bin/bash

if read COUNT < <(mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface -E mylovelydb <<< "SELECT COUNT(*) AS __COUNT__ FROM mylittletable WHERE thenumber=$THENUMBER;" | sed -ne '/^__COUNT__/{ s/^.* //; p; }') && [[ COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "AHHH THAT'S ALREADY THERE"
else
    mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb <<< "INSERT INTO mylittletable VALUES ('$THENUMBER,'$THEDATE');"
fi
```

You could aslo make them a little expanded with variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

SELECTCOMMAND="SELECT COUNT(*) AS __COUNT__ FROM mylittletable WHERE thenumber=$THENUMBER;"
INSERTCOMMAND="INSERT INTO mylittletable VALUES ('$THENUMBER,'$THEDATE');"

if read COUNT < <(mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface -E mylovelydb <<< "$SELECTCOMMAND" | sed -ne '/^__COUNT__/{ s/^.* //; p; }') && [[ COUNT -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "AHHH THAT'S ALREADY THERE"
else
    mysql --host=192.168.0.0 --user=garfunkle --password=spatulaface mylovelydb <<< "$INSERTCOMMAND"
fi
```